# Display inline not work and my item automatically stair

Tags: css

I use this code for list sub category in landing page
i need display item inline
inline not work properly

```
<div class="subcategories">
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.subcategories{
      position:relative;
}
.subcategories ul{
overflow:hidden;
}
.subcategories li{
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    margin:4px;
    border: 1px solid#5fa5c8;
    width: 24%;
    height: 230px;
}
.subcategories img{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px -71px 15px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.subcategories li span {
    display: block;
    margin: -8px 0 ;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color:#08c;
    line-height: 18px;
    font: 12px/1 YekanWeb,Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

What is finally seen

1
------2
----------3
----------------4
i need 
1    2    3    4

Is there a problem with my CSS?

Comment: If the answer below answered your question, please mark this as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`

https://jsfiddle.net/3of7xdtv/

**OR**

try using `display: flex;` on your parent div. Take off the float and the display: inline of child css.

https://jsfiddle.net/tractionworks/v0h912wk/2/

Comment: @user3485709 Did that help your inline issues?